# CSS/JS not loading on IOS, seemingly no cause, can't replicate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Okay, so I've made a web dev site (ironic given that I can't fix it, I know.) and some users are reporting that only the HTML is loading and no CSS/JS is. It seems to mainly be affecting IOS users, and we can't replicate the error ourselves. We've had one instance of it occurring off of IOS.

```
/*Our only CSS file*/
<link rel="preload" href="css/min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min.css"></noscript>

/* Example of how we use JS files */
<script async src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

We gzip our files before sending them across too if that has any effect?
Our styles are vendor-prefixed too so it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

Link preloading doesn't appear to be supported in iOS Safari. At least according to this: https://caniuse.com/#search=preload

A standard CSS link should work just fine, at least until support for preload is more widespread.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/min.css">
```